# Suggest solutions book

Tags: soft-question, book-recommendation, cryptography

Does somebody know solutions manual for book "An Introduction to Mathematical Cryptography" by Jeffrey Hoffstein, Jill Pipher, Joseph H. Silverman?

Comment: why don't you contact the publisher or author of the original book?